# Get The Selected Role On Edit or Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've a DropDownList - `ASP.NET` WebForm where it's filled up with roles and did it like the below from database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
      LoadDropDownBox();
   }
}

public void LoadDropDownBox() 
{ 
   ddlUserRole.DataSource = aDbOperations.GetRoles(); //List of objects here 

   ddlUserRole.DataTextField = "roleName"; 
   ddlUserRole.DataValueField = "roleId"; 

   ddlUserRole.DataBind(); 
}
```

It works fine. Now my requirement is to get the selected role of a user when I edit or update user details. So say a user has role **Admin**, then while editing, the admin role should be selected by default along with other values in the **DropDownList**. So I tried something like this in the same default page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
      foreach (var item in aDbOperations.GetUserWithId(id)) //Passing query string here to match the id of the editing details
      { 
         ddlUserRole.Value = item.roleName; //Get the selected role name by default while editing user details 
      }
      LoadDropDownBox();  
   }
}
```

Even tried this:

```
ddlUserRole.SelectedItem.Value = item.roleName;
```

Though it didn't work and not getting the value selected by default along with other role values from database. Anything missed here?

**Update - 1**: Even tried the below one, but still not done

```
if (ddlUserRole.Items.FindByText(item.roleName.ToString()) != null)
{
   ddlUserRole.Items.FindByText(item.roleName.ToString()).Selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your foreach after the LoadDropDownBox() function because the drop down has no loaded values before then.

Then if you know your dropdown contains the value FOR SURE then you can just do

```
ddlUserRole.SelectedValue = item.roleId.ToString();
```

Otherwise you would need to do a check to prevent an error like so:

```
ListItem selectedListItem = ddlUserRole.Items.FindByValue(item.roleId.ToString());

if (selectedListItem != null)
{
    selectedListItem.Selected = true;
}
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
        if(!IsPostBack)
           {

              LoadDropDownBox();  

    foreach (var item in aDbOperations.GetUserWithId(id)) //Passing query string here to match the id of the editing details
              { 
                ListItem selectedListItem = ddlUserRole.Items.FindByValue(item.roleId.ToString());

if (selectedListItem != null)
{
    selectedListItem.Selected = true;
}
              }
           }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly @Drewskis and Thanks for it.